# Child Requesting OnChange request of Parent Window element

Tags: javascript, iframe, element, parent, onchange

So I have this in my child iframe has this code running with in it.

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("cs_0000").onchange = function () {
    alert('Worked');
};
```

For what ever reason it's not working.

I can run this code:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("cs_0000").value;
```

and it will return the value of that element but the on change event doesn't work.

Comment: I figured how to capture the change.

window.parent.jQuery(variable).on('change', function(){
// do stuff here
    });

Answer (score 0):

The result was because the hidden fields don't trigger change events.

So after using:

```
.trigger("change");
```

I was able to catch the event using:

```
window.parent.jQuery('#something').on('change', function(){
    // Put stuff here
});
```